# FineUploader onDeleteComplete

Tags: fine-uploader

How can I implement the onDeleteComplete, do I put inside the deletefile: request or outside?

I've used the complete method before and I tried to implement the onDeleteComplete the same way but I get no actions. Below is the code I've tried to use but it fails.

```
   $('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
                    request: {
                        endpoint: '/Test.aspx'
                    },
                    deleteFile: {
                        enabled: true,
                        endpoint: '/Test.aspx'
                    }
                }).on('onDeleteComplete', function (id, xhr, isError) {
                    alert('hi');
                })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of callbacks when using the jQuery plug-in is well documented in both the examples/demos on fineuploader.com and in the documentation.  There are two distinct places in the documentation where us of callbacks are mentioned: the [callbacks readme page](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/events.html) and in the [callbacks section of the using the jQuery plugin readme page](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/modes/using-jquery-plugin.html#callbacks).

The "on" in `"onDeleteComplete"` in your code is redundant, it should be changed to `.on("deleteComplete", ...)`.  Also, the first parameter passed to all event handlers by jQuery is "event".

Please read the documentation, starting with the first page at http://docs.fineuploader.com/.  Read the introductory info, then follow the path outlined based on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally got it working with your suggestion.

Here my final code

```
       $('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
            request: {
                endpoint: '/Test.aspx'
            },
            deleteFile: {
                enabled: true,
                endpoint: '/Test.aspx'
            }
        }).on('deleteComplete', function (event, id, name, responseJSON) {
          alert('hi');
        });
```

Comment: Also, your callback is still not correct, as far as the parameters are concerned.  Please have a look at [the documentation](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/docs/callbacks.md).

Answer (score 0):

How about now?

```
$('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
            request: {
                endpoint: '/Test.aspx'
            },
            deleteFile: {
                enabled: true,
                endpoint: '/Test.aspx'
            }
        }).on('deleteComplete', function (id, xhr, isError) {
          alert('hi');
        });
```

Comment: You still need the event parameter.  Please delete this answer and simply edit your other answer.